# React.js material-ui: Is it possible to sort amount when it is masked with commas?

Tags: reactjs

I have a material-table which has a `Total Amount` column

The sorting on this columns works before I added masking of commas since there are amounts
e.g.
1,000.00

Is the built-in sorting of ascending/descending of `material-table` can be modified to work with masked amounts?

Thank you

Please see edits.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

> Is the built-in sorting of ascending/descending of material-table can
> be modified to work with masked amounts?

Yes, its possible. You need to use a custom sort. Use `customSort` method in your column array to pass a functions that sorts for you.

```
<MaterialTable
      title="Custom Filtering Algorithm Preview"
      columns={[
        {
          title: 'Name', 
          field: 'name',
          customSort: (a, b) => a.name.length - b.name.length
        },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
```

More info here https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/sorting

In your case its

```
{
  title: "Total Amount",
  field: "totalAmount",
  filtering: false,
  customSort: (a, b) => { ... write your sort logic here}
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, according to material-table docs, you can change sorting alghoritm by set a function to `column.customSort`. Check [here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/sorting)